# How are related apps calculated in android market

Tags: android, google-play

Someone can give some information about how related apps are calculated in android market?
Why for example X is related to Y but Y isn't related to X?

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen Google publish any details of this, and I wouldn't expect them to as it's commercially sensitive, but I expect the algorithm takes into account some or all of these:

- Apps with similar names
- Apps that comes up together in searches
- Apps that are often viewed in the same session by users
- Apps that have both been bought/installed by the same person
- Apps that are in the same category

The algorithm will share some characteristics with the algorithm Amazon uses to recommend similar products.

Answer (score -2):

I've seen descriptions of apps where the developer simply stated "similar to the following apps: ... " and listed them all.

Now that the length for descriptions has been increased, this would seem like a decent solution to accurately define similar apps.

Comment: whoever downvoted this: would be nice to get a reason so that we can learn from it.

Comment: FYI: the description of my app contains words that subsequently appear in the titles of "Related" apps. Therefore my suggestion here is actually quite accurate

Comment: Not really. The related comes when people who have App A install App B. When enough people do this, it will appear in the relate. 

Just adding do not affect this "related" change. But people who look for the "related" App have a higher chance of finding (and viewing/installing) your app and if enough people do that it will increase the likehood. But just placing the word in the text alone doesn't do it.

Comment: For example, when people Looking for Angry Birds and you add Angry Birds to your description, then your game will be listed in the "Angry Birds" search results. But this alone doesn't do anything. Only if people who searching for "angry birds" look (and/or install) your app it will increase the likehood that your angry birds will show as "related apps" in your app description.